# ClassCastException when trying to get XDesktop instance with OpenOffice API

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I've been developing an OpenOffice Writer extension. Currently, I need to retrieve the current document object. The following should return the current component as a Writer document.

```
XMultiComponentFactory factory = context.getServiceManager();
XDesktop desktop = (XDesktop) factory.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", context);
XTextDocument document = (XTextDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, desktop.getCurrentComponent());

return document;
```

My problem happens when the second line is run. The following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to com.sun.star.frame.XDesktop
```

Why is the `createInstanceWithContext` returning something which does not conform to the requested interface? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the docs [here](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Using_the_Desktop), there is a two step process to get the interface:

```
          Object desktop = xRemoteServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext (
              "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xRemoteContext);
          XDesktop xDesktop = (XDesktop)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XDesktop.class, desktop);
```

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was missing. Thanks!